# Why is $f([x]_3)=[5x]_6$ not well-defined but $f([x]_3)=[2x]_6$ is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing

As the title suggests, I am having difficulty determining what makes one of the functions well-defined and the other not.

I am trying to show/explain why $f([x]_3)=[5x]_6$ is not well-defined while $f([x]_3)=[2x]_6$ is.

I know that if a function $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is well defined, then if $x_1=x_2 \in X$ then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

I started like this...

$f([0]_3)=[0]_6$

$f([1]_3)=[5]_6$

$f([2]_3)=[10]_6=[4]_6$

I think this last line is where the problem is (why the function is not well-defined) but I'm not sure I am thinking about this the right way. I am just not sure how to use the usual rule. This last line's issue does not come up in the second function.

Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, your title uses $[]_3,$ but the body has some $[]_6.$ $[x]_3\mapsto [5x]_6$ is not well-defined, while the $x\mapsto [2x]_6$ is well-defined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews this is a problem from my book that is asking to explain why the first one isn't well-defined, so I figure it must not be but I'm not sure I see how to explain that

Comment: Ah so sorry, that is what I meant to type. Will fix it @ThomasAndrews

Comment: What is $f([3]_3)$?

Comment: More generally, what does $[x]_3$ mean? The equivalence class of all numbers conguent to $x$ modulo 3?

Comment: Your last question is backwards. Remember that $[3]_3 = [0]_3$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, but wouldn't this also happen in the second function? Making both of them not well-defined?

Comment: Did you try? What is $2\cdot 3k$?

Comment: Given $[0]_3=[3]_3,$ what do you get for $[x]_3\mapsto [5x]_6?$

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $k,$ the map $[x]_3\mapsto[kx]_6$ is well-defined iff, as you said:
$$[x]_3=[y]_3\Rightarrow[kx]_6=[ky]_6,$$
i.e.
$$3\mid x-y\Rightarrow6\mid k(x-y).$$
This condition is equivalent to: for any multiple $z$ of $3,$ $kz$ is a multiple of $6,$ i.e. to: $k3$ is a multiple of $6,$
i.e. to: $k$ is even.

So your first map is not well-defined because $5$ is odd, and your second map is well-defined because $2$ is even.

Comment: Upvote for your being so responsive to my comment. Although I would never write $k3$ unless I was talking about $K3$ surfaces in algebraic geometry. :)

Comment: Your comment was very useful (to me for the future, and hopefully to Sophie if she hasn't fled away by my fault). Shall I delete my previous answer, or leave it for readers of another level?

Comment: I felt bound to write $k3$ (and not $3k$) to help Sophie to understand it is  $kz$ for $z=3.$

Answer (score 0):

Given a group homomorphism $\varphi:G\to H$ and a normal subgroup $K\triangleleft G,$ you have a well-defined homomorphism $G/K\to H,\;gK\mapsto\varphi(g)$ iff $K\subset\ker\varphi.$

The kernel of the morphism $\varphi_1:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z,\;x\mapsto[5x]_6$ is $6\Bbb Z,$ which does not contain $3\Bbb Z.$

The kernel of the morphism $\varphi_2:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z,\;x\mapsto[2x]_6$ is $3\Bbb Z.$

Comment: My opinion is that this answer is not at a level appropriate for the OP.

Comment: @TedShifrin Perhaps, but answers are not only for the OP, but also for other (future) readers who have similar questions, i.e. this site is not intended as an ephemeral stream of answers but rather as an everlastig repository of good answers (hopefully evolving to "proofs from the book").

Comment: @BillDubuque yes, future readears will ceartnly search for this question and answer.